# Footer coming on top of forms. Bootstrap3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, footer

My problem is - footer is coming on top of every form.
My base.html.twig looks like this:

```
<div class="footer navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom" id="footer">
<footer class="container" >
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="#">Regulamin</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Polityka prywatności</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</footer>
```

And its the look of the page [footer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0laFF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer would be similar to the case with the navbar-fixed-top. Could you try and set padding-bottom: 70px to your body element?
[As it stated in doc](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-component-alignment)

Comment: Well that helped, lols. Sometimes i think im too dumb for this... Thanks for fast reply, much appreciate!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to place this in your footer? `clear:both;`